# What type of display connector is this for a computer monitor?

Tags: gpu, dvi, connector

I've just built my first compute and I'm wondering what type of port this is?

Sorry for the poor quality, it has a singular line, if there is any confusion.

[image: output port]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a female [Digital Visual Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface) DVI-D Dual Link port. Wikipedia has a [list of video connectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_video_connectors) which is helpful in these situations.

[image]

<sub>(source: Wikipedia)</sub>

Comment: This is basically a DVI port that can handle 2 monitors.  You need the "dual-head" cables to connect 2 monitors to this.

Comment: @Lawrence You are referring to `Dual-Head` not `Dual-Link` see the [connector section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface#Connector) of the above link. Cite: Dual link should not be confused with dual display (also known as dual head), which is a configuration consisting of a single computer connected to two monitors, sometimes using a DMS-59 connector for two single link DVI connections.